# How do I alias gsed to sed on OSX in both the terminal, but also make it available in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, macos

I have gnu-sed installed, that I installed using brew install.
I can use gnu-sed aka gsed as a drop in replacement for BSD Sed on OSX
by adding this to my ~/.bash_profile:

`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

But when I run a bash script that makes use of sed, it defaults back to BSD sed.
How do I set a default alias of sed to point to gsed globally even in bash scripts.

The reason for doing this. Is I want to be able to use the same scripts that make use of GNUSed on both Linux and OSX.

Comment: You don't. Aliases don't work in scripts by design. File-in-the-PATH is the only right thing, and unless your script overrides the PATH, it **will** see the one from its parent process.

Comment: (There's an additional wrong thing available, insofar as you can export a function and scripts executed by bash -- not zsh, not sh, just bash -- will see it; but don't do that; have a directory containing the `sed` you want in the PATH first).

Comment: Anyhow -- when you claim this isn't honored by a script, some random generic script isn't good enough to diagnose. We need to know the execution environment (was the script started from a shell that executed your .bash_profile or by a GUI app?), the content (does the script hardcode `/usr/bin/sed` or such? Does it set the PATH itself?), etc; and otherwise a [mre] -- enough details to see the problem with our own eyes.

Comment: Alternately, consider adding something like the following to your script: `if command -v gsed >/dev/null 2>&1; then sed() { command gsed "$@"; }; fi` -- leaves `sed` alone _unless_ there exists a `gsed` command, at which point it creates a function wrapper.

Comment: Is it named `gsed`? If not, make a link to `gsed`? Good luck!

Comment: The compatibility problems between GNU and bsd `sed`s, run both ways, so making `sed` = `gsed` in scripts may break scripts written for macOS (or even built into macOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run :

```
ln -fs /usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin/gsed /usr/local/bin/sed
```

then put in your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

this way your scripts (using sed) will run across Linux & MacOS.

Comment: Thanks wow this worked. Only difference is my gsed was in slightly different location so I used. ```sudo ln -fs /opt/homebrew/bin/gsed /usr/local/bin/sed``` Thanks allot!

Comment: Glad this helps. On MacOS, `/usr/local/*` should not belong to root.

Comment: I checked on my system and /usr/local/bin/* belongs to root by default